# Operations with events and probabilities

Tags: probability

please define the $P(A), P(B), P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A|B)$ probability if $P(A^c\cup B^c) = 4/5,\\P(B^c) = 1/3 ~\text{and }~P(A\cup B) = 4/5$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Please consider learning [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Are the events $A$ and $B$ independent?

Comment: @MattiP. Does it matter? Even without that assumption, you have four pieces of information, which should determine everything.

Comment: The question is: are the events A and B independent.

Comment: @Matt Do you know what the definition of 'independent' is?

Comment: @Matt No, that's not the question. It's actually entirely irrelevant whether they are independent (I don't think they are, but I haven't actually checked, and it really doesn't matter).

Comment: My teacher askd to do it in Maple, but we haven't used it in the lessons.
I don't konw if the events A B are indepentent or not. It is not given.

Answer (score 0):

The sets $A\cap B$, $A^{\complement}\cap B$, $A\cap B^{\complement}$ and $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}$ form a partition of the whole space. So the corresponding probabilities add up to $1$ and if these probabilities are found then of every set that is a some union of these events we can find the probability.

Observe that $A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}=(A\cap B)^{\complement}$.

So: $$P(A\cap B)=1-P(A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement})=1-\frac45=\frac15\tag1$$

Then $1=P(\Omega)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^{\complement}\cap B)+P(B^{\complement})=\frac15+P(A^{\complement}\cap B)+\frac13$ so: $$P(A^{\complement}\cap B)=1-\frac13-\frac15=\frac7{15}\tag2$$

On base of $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}=(A\cup B)^{\complement}$ also:$$P(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})=1-\frac45=\frac15\tag3$$

Finally we find: $$P(A\cap B^{\complement})=1-\frac15-\frac7{15}-\frac15=\frac2{15}\tag4$$

Can you take it from here?